# Why does else if( 2 > 1) { System.out.println(" hello") ;} is not working?

Tags: java

Problem in infix to postfix conversion

> at the point when value fetched is '-' then the compiler does not enter at else-if block (last case)

```
package com.conversion;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class mainclass {

    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s;

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a complete expresion");
        s= sc.next();

        stackop ob = new stackop(); 

        System.out.println("YOUR PROVIDED input expression is :"+s);
        //System.out.print(" Equivalent postfix notation is :  ");
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        ob.postfix(s);

    }

}


class stackop{

    char stack1[]=new char[50];
    int top;

    void push(char ch)
        {
        top++;
        stack1[top]=ch; 
        System.out.println(" element pushed is: "+ch);

        System.out.println("----- current value of top is after push overs :  "+top+"  -------");

        }
    char pop(){
        char ch;
        ch= stack1[top];
        //System.out.println("current value of top is :  "+top);
        System.out.println(" element popped is: "+ch);
        --top;
        System.out.println("----- current value of top is after pop overs :  "+top+"  -------");
        return ch; 
    }

    boolean isalpha(char a)
        {
            if((a>='a' && a<='z')||(a>=0 && a<=9))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    boolean operator(char ch)
    {
        if(ch=='/'||ch=='*'||ch=='+'||ch=='-')
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
    int prech(char ch){
            switch(ch)
            {
                case '-': return 1;
                //break;
                case '+': return 1;
                //break;
                case '/': return 2;
                //break;
                case '*': return 2;
            }
            return 0;
    }

    void postfix(String str)
    {

        char otop=0;
        char[] output = new char[str.length()+1];

        for(int i=0 ; i<str.length();i++)
        {
            char ch=str.charAt(i);
            System.out.println("==========value fetched is  "+ch+"    ===========");

            if(ch=='(')
                push(ch);
            else if(isalpha(ch))
            {
                System.out.println("elemnt inserted in output list is :"+ch);
                output[++otop]=ch;
            }
            else if(ch == ')' )
            {   
                char temp=0;
                System.out.println(" a close bracket  is encounterd  ");
                while((temp=pop())!='(')
                {
                    output[++otop]=temp;
                    System.out.println("elemnt inserted in output list is :"+temp);
                }
            }
            else if(operator(ch))
            {
                if(prech(stack1[top])==0||(prech(stack1[top])<=prech(ch))||(prech(stack1[top])=='('))
                    push(ch);
            }
            else if(prech(stack1[top]) > prech(ch))
            {
                System.out.println(" hahah  here i come");
                output[++otop]=pop();
                push(ch);
            }

        }
        while(top>0)
        {
            output[++otop]=pop();
            System.out.println("elemnt inserted in output list is :"+output[otop]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nOUTPUT OF EXPRESSION  IS  :   " );
        for(int j=0;j<str.length();j++)
        {
            System.out.print(""+output[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A bunch of irrelavant code + incomprehensible question.

Comment: create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and format you question properly first

Comment: there's not even a single appearance of `else if( 2 > 1) { System.out.println(“ hello”) ;}` in your code. And if it doesn't go to this `else`, it may well go into the previous `if`

Comment: If you had properly read the code, you would know which line he is referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this chunk of code:

```
else if(operator(ch))
{
    if(prech(stack1[top])==0||(prech(stack1[top])<=prech(ch))||(prech(stack1[top])=='('))
                push(ch);
}
else if(prech(stack1[top]) > prech(ch))
```

The `operator(ch)` method returns true for your operators, which means  control flow never reaches the second `else if`. What you probably want to do is move it inside the first `else if`, as shown below:

```
else if(operator(ch))
{
    if(prech(stack1[top])==0||(prech(stack1[top])<=prech(ch))||(prech(stack1[top])=='('))
    {
        push(ch);
    }
    else if(prech(stack1[top]) > prech(ch)) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The title and the question do not have anything in common, also you should format your code. Nonetheless here's my answer to the question which you probably would've asked had you written an appropriate title.

Well actually 0 != '0' in programming, because '0' is translated to it's integer value which in ASCII is 48 and the comparison is between 0 and 48. 
So your isalpha method should look like this:

```
boolean isalpha(char a)
{
    if((a>='a' && a<='z')||(a>='0' && a<='9'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Also, there are these neat little methods with which you don't need to check characters' ASCII code to compare them. I personally prefer this approachh as it is more simple and concise. It would look like this:

```
boolean isalpha(char a)
{
    return Character.isDigit(a) || Character.isAlphabetic(a);
}
```